# How to update ReSharper Command Line Tools in Team City

Tags: teamcity, resharper

I am looking to update ReSharper CLT in Team City to resolve one of the errors as mentioned in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32117999/2579850)

ReSharper CLT seems to be part of .Net tools in Team City and not sure if there is a way to update this plug-in. Please can someone let me know the best way to update ReSharper CLT on Team City so all agents are updated automatically?

Comment: AFAIK, .NET tools can't be updated independently of TeamCity. That said, there is also the possibility to include CLT as a NuGet package in your solution, and then reference it from your build scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no easy way to update the plugin. At the moment the recommended way is to upgrade TeamCity. TeamCity 9.1.5 is bundled with ReSharper command line tools 10.0.2 release. 
We have a [request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-39358) to provide an easy way to update bundled ReSharper command line tools. Please vote for it.